# Ordering multi-dimensional array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, statistics

Lets say I have a multidimensional array [A][B][C], and I want to order the array with respect to `A`, of course the relationship of the values of `B` and `C` which corresponded to their neighboring `A` needs to be maintained.
Also, assuming we have multiple `A`s with the same value, how do we order the `B`s so that we have `A` ordered primarily then `B` ordered if its possible.

Something like:

```
(1,2,3)
(1,3,7)
(1,4,5)
(1,5,2)
(2,3,5)
(2,4,9)
(2,5,0)
...
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your data was not already sorted:

```
data = [(1,2,3),
        (1,3,7),
        (1,4,5),
        (1,5,2),
        (2,3,5),
        (2,4,9),
        (2,5,0)]
```

Then [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) will return a sorted `list`:

```
sorted_data = sorted(data)
```